# Can I make this (Python) regular expression any faster?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches a string of the form `##-##` (where # corresponds to any digit), with the caveat that the second pair of digits can't be "00". The expression should be usable with [re.search](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.search) and should capture the first occurrence of the matching pattern.

Here's what I've got (which works):

```
the_regex = re.compile("(\d\d-(?:0[123456789]|[123456789]\d))")
```

I'm not wild about the branch or the long character groups. Can anyone suggest a better (more clear, or optionally, more efficient) regex?

(Yes, this is a micro-optimization, and I've heeded the proper warnings from Knuth.)

Comment: Should it match when the string contains something like: `123-123`? (You current expression (and all the answers thus far) enforces no boundary conditions and will match the: `23-12` within: `123-123`.)

Comment: @ridgerunner good point, but in this case the strings it's matching against are guaranteed not to have that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other possibility... i wasn't sure if this would work, but it appears to.... it uses lookahead assertions:

```
r2 = re.compile(r"(\d\d-(?!00)\d\d)")
l = re.findall(r2, 'On 02-14 I went looking for 12-00 and 14-245')
print l
['02-14', '14-24']
```

However... it doesn't appear to be any faster (comparing to above solution). In fact, the original solution is the fastest here:

```
# Martijn/Aaron's solution
In [20]: %timeit l = re.findall(the_regex2, '11-01 11-99 10-29 01-99 00-00 11-00')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.55 µs per loop

# Above version
In [21]: %timeit l = re.findall(r2, '11-01 11-99 10-29 01-99 00-00 11-00')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.49 µs per loop

#Original post's version.
In [25]: the_regex = re.compile("(\d\d-(?:0[123456789]|[123456789]\d))")
In [26]: %timeit l = re.findall(the_regex, '11-01 11-99 10-29 01-99 00-00 11-00')    
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.41 µs per loop
```

Comment: Or `re.compile("(\d\d-(?:(?!00)\d\d))")` to keep the `(?:)` in OPs.

Comment: I don't think that hurts anything, but I don't think it's necessary... the original is just done that way because the `|` has to be in a group, and if you don't mark it as non-capturing it becomes a separate group. The `\d\d` aren't in a separate group in this one, and the `(?!00)` term is already non-capturing, so it doesn't actually add anything, I think.

Comment: In my test cases (I should have shown some example data), this proved to be the fastest (by a fairly small margin, admittedly).

Answer (score 4):

The long character group is easily solved with using a character range instead:

```
r"(\d\d-(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d))"
```

but you cannot avoid the branch here.

Comment: beat me by three minutes.

Answer (score 3):

```
the_regex = re.compile("(\d\d-(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d))")



l = re.findall(the_regex, '11-01 11-99 10-29 01-99 00-00 11-00')
print l
```

shows:

```
['11-01', '11-99', '10-29', '01-99']
```

if you use re.finditer, it returns a generator, which may be better for you:

```
it = re.finditer(the_regex, '11-01 11-99 10-29 01-99 00-00 11-00')
print type(it)
print list(i.group(0) for i in it)
```

shows this:

```
<type 'callable-iterator'>
['11-01', '11-99', '10-29', '01-99']
```